# how can run an activex control in ie7 without admin privileges?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7, activex, admin

i understand that with ie8 microsoft has improved the active x experience but i am dealing with a large installed base of xp-ie7 systems and a system admin who doesn't want to upgrade.

if the system is logged in with admin privileges, install and subsequent run work great.  if the ystem is logged in without privilege we can neither install nor run.  if we install with admin and fall back to non admin, our controls don't load but we don't get any diagnostic feedback that we have been able to find.

one possible twist on the cause of the problem is that our active x are written in c# instead of c++, a nuance that the person before me didn't fully appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_compat), it is not supported: You need both windows Vista and IE8. So upgrading IE alone won't help you.

There is actually something called [registration free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx), but that only works if you can control the .exe file hosting the COM components. And COM overlaps, but is not exactly the same as ActiveX, so it might not work anyways.

Your best bet is to provide this sysadmin with an MSI file that the admin can pro-actively push to all sysems on the site. Make sure that .net gets thrown into the package. You should invests some time to test that your binaries install flawlessly everywhere. Also consider that you won't be able to upgrade the deployed version from your web page. So your upgrades there should be compatible with the existing activex, or done synchronous with the activex deployment.

If deployment is a problem, discuss the issue with the site's management, so they can require the admin to cooperate.